# Piwik API: How to get a list of top visited URLs within a website sub-directory?

Tags: json, httprequest, analytics, matomo, usage-statistics

I'm looking to get a lit of top three visited urls from a website within a specific sub-directory. For example, top three URLs from http://www.website.com/news/ (while all the pages on http://www.website.com are being tracked).

It'd be amazing if the API could return clean urls (such as, without referral tracking like utm_source=campaign).

I'm looking to get it returned with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so at this time there is no way to accurately get a list of top urls based on metrics. This is because they are broken down based on '/' character into categories and no actual URL strings are being recorded anywhere convenient.

A good way to do this is to define a custom variable and push the browser URL there:

```
_paq.push(['setCustomVariable', 1,'url', window.location.href, 'visit']);
```

You can also clean that URL from campaign values using the following JavaScript function

```
removeURLCampaigns: function(search){
    if(search.indexOf('&') > -1){
        search = search.split('&').filter(function(v) {
            return !/^utm_/.test(v);
        }).join('&');
    }
    if(search.indexOf('?') > -1){
        search = search.split('?').filter(function(v) {
            return !/^utm_/.test(v);
        }).join('?');
    }

    return search;
}
```

You can then use Piwik API call with **CustomVariables.getCustomVariablesValuesFromNameId**, sort by **filter_sort_column=sum_daily_nb_uniq_visitors** (daily unique visitors) and make sure that your order is descending: **filter_sort_order=desc**. You can also limit your results: **filter_limit=1**